# Purge of inactive memory fails

Tags: macos, memory, purge

In total I have 14 GB of RAM. Currently, 1.5 GB is free and 3.9 GB is inactive.

I tried to purge my inactive memory. Both

```
$ purge
```

and

```
$ sudo purge
```

returned

```
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 14603, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x104050da0 ("logical-processor-core:Core 2"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "logical-processor-core:Core 2", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 34319, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x1070c6030 ("PCI-device:Generic PCI Device"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "PCI-device:Generic PCI Device", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 14359, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x101685120 ("logical-processor-core:Core"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "logical-processor-core:Core", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 34587, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x1044c3560 ("logical-processor-core:Core 2 (Penryn)"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "logical-processor-core:Core 2 (Penryn)", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 38939, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x1016bea00 ("logical-processor-core:Nehalem"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "logical-processor-core:Nehalem", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPAddressSpace.c:608>  Unable to open user client for address space 30243, error 0xe00002bd.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4013>   Unable to get all available address spaces.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4384>   Unable to [fully] instantiate device instances for loaded device record 0x1040205d0 ("logical-processor-core:Xeon 5100"), error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPDevice.c:4805>   Unable to instantiate instances of new device "logical-processor-core:Xeon 5100", error kCPUnknownError.
[ERROR] <CPOSX.c:1172>  Unable to get user client so as to poke the kernel.
Unable to purge disk buffers, error #-2.
```

What are all these errors?
How can I purge my inactive memory?

---

I am on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Comment: Did you run it as root or using `sudo`?

Comment: I did both. Same outputs. Post edited to add this info. Thanks